# Show results between :year field in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i haved a Cars scaffold with a field year type string. Im interesting to select two years between two select_box and display the Cars between the selected years.

I started testing in console with:

```
Car.maximum(:year)
```

and

```
Car.minimum(:year)
```

But when i starting testing with:

```
Car.where((self.maximum(:year))..(self.minimum(:year)))
```

I lost the head, any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

**THE SOLUTION**

In the model cars.rb add a method:

```
def self.year(fyear,tyear)
  result = order('new DESC')
  result = where(:year => fyear..tyear) if fyear.present? && tyear.present? 
  result
end
```

then in cars_controller.rb add to the index method:

```
@cars = Car.year(params[:fyear],params[:tyear])
```

Finally, on the view index.html.erb add the form you select the two year fields:

```
<%= form_for cars_path, :method => :get do %>
  <label>Mínimo</label>
  <%= select_tag :fyear, options_for_select(Car.all.map &:year) %>
  <br />
  <label>Máximo</label>
  <%= select_tag :tyear, options_for_select(Car.all.map &:year) %>
  <br />
  <%= submit_tag "Buscar", :name => nil %>
</form>
<% end %>
```

thank you beck03076, user2564200 and Abimael Martell

Answer (score 0):

Change the model method to this,

```
    def self.search(search,from,to) 
      result = order('new DESC') 
      result = joins(:model => :brand).where('brands.title LIKE ? OR    models.title LIKE ? AND cars.year BETWEEN ? AND ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%",from,to).order('new DESC') if search.present? 
      result
    end
```

And call it from the controller like this,

```
#@cars = Car.search("Volkswagen Vento",2007,2009)
@cars = Car.search(params[:query],params[:from],params[:to])
```

Comment: oops..from and to can be keywords in ruby so use, fyear and tyear.

Comment: beck03076 thank you, I dont have errors, but still dont show the select results, i haved this in the range select form... <%= form_for cars_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
<label>Min</label>
<%= f.select :fyear, Car.all.collect {|c| [ c.year, c.id ] } %>
<label>Max</label>
<%= f.select :tyear, Car.all.collect {|c| [ c.year, c.id ] } %>
<%= f.submit "search", :name => nil %>
</form>
<% end %>

Comment: <%= select_tag "#{f.object_name}[:tyear]",options_for_select(Car.all.map &:year) %>

Comment: beck03076 i made the changes, but continue show all results. model https://gist.github.com/stanmx/9718ca3d05d36f3619db / controller https://gist.github.com/stanmx/a70a7aee5ff797443cf8 / view https://gist.github.com/stanmx/cae0fe65cc3eb5d657e3

Comment: i check the log https://gist.github.com/stanmx/0711fe3bc284bf764ee6 and dont make the search.

Comment: From the log i see, our search action in the car model is not called at all.. Post all the code of the car model and also from the log, I see this params hash.. {"utf8"=>"✓", "/cars"=>{":fyear"=>"1999", ":tyear"=>"2010"}}.. This hash should have the key, "cars" and there is no "search", value.. long way to go to make it work.. I will help you.. dont worry... can you come on stack exchange chat???

Comment: beck03076 thank you! i post the solution in the same space of the anwser. I create a new method to fix this. See it.

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you :D.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions

Comment: You should provide a little bit more context when answering with a link. What if the link goes down?